# Abstract appeared in the abstract book of a conference but the paper is not published, can I publish it elsewhere?

Tags: publications, publishability

I intended to participate in a conference, I sent my abstract and it was accepted. For some reasons, I didn't go to that conference and I didn't send my final conference paper.

However, my abstract (title, authors, abstract, keywords) is shown in the published ***abstract book*** of the conference and can be easily found online.

My question, since I didn't publish that work, I want to publish that same work in a different conference now, can I use the same abstract? Or I have to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In my field you don't publish the same but you can present more than twice. Because conferences aren't journals but are seen as moments of discussion and dissemination of ideas and results.

I would avoid the same wording anyway. This gives idea of laziness at least if one is not sure to have found *the perfect wording*.

It might be different in fields where conferences are seen as the major source for results, but still, up to date, your results are not in the wild and they just left a trace as simple abstract.

Comment: The practices of your field are not universal. In others, conferences publish proceedings and they may be considered more important and essential than journal articles.

Comment: @Buffy there is not proceeding out, yet. Nor there was a presentation. Basically the only existing thing is something more than a title submitted to a conference and never discussed. I've mentioned my field to say that in many if not most one can apply for conf. presentation as long as one and the organizers/audience like. The resulting proceeding(s), if is unavoidable that each presentation has an accompanying one, are just paraphrases or contain small variations. The full paper, if any, Is usually prepared and submitted separately to a standard journal for a standard issue.

Comment: To the OP and just related. Being accepted and not showing up requires at least a general explanation to the organizers. Considers that some others contributions were rejected not solely for their insufficient quality but mostly because a conference has limitations in terms of time and, for posters, space.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you agreed to originally. It is possible, though unlikely, that you gave up copyright to your work when you submitted it or later in the process. If you did give up copyright then you have to deal with that fact. One way is to ask to have it returned to you since the paper wasn't published. Giving an *exclusive* license would be similar to giving up copyright.

But if you hold all rights then the paper is yours. But you might want to modify it slightly. At least enough to cite the abstract.

Comment: let's say I will paraphrase all my abstract. How about the results in the abstract? they will stay the same (same meanings), the numbers also will stay the same (the abstract contains some % numbers). Can I mention the same results from the original abstract?

Comment: Your questions can really only be answered by an editor for the journal. I would guess that you are fine. Make sure the editor knows about the abstract, of course.

Comment: Copyright is irrelevant here. I don't see why we should escalate the situation with hypothetical formal outcomes. There is no paper out. The author should avoid exactly the same wording and that is.